# How to add border to JMenu button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jmenu, jmenuitem

I can't add border to JMenu button, looks like setBorder methods works only with JMenuItem.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
public Test() {
   initUI();
}

private void initUI() {


    // creating menuBar
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    // creating menu and adding border
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Some menu");
    menu.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));

    // creating item and adding border (the same way)
    JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Some item");
    item1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));

    // adding all together
    menu.add(item1);
    menuBar.add(menu);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    // basic settings for the window
    setTitle("Testing JMenu");
    setSize(360, 250);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        Test test =new Test();
        test.setVisible(true);
    });
}
}
```

The result is as follows; I expected black frames around both JMenu and JMenuItem

[Picture of created GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9R9y.png)

Comment: It works well for me: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ugI0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ugI0.png) There is a border in both JMenu and JMenuItem. I don't understand where is your problem !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMenu is more complex. You might have to edit it like this:

```
UIManager.put("PopupMenu.border", new LineBorder(Color.RED));
```

You can check the javadocs for UIManager at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html

You can then check the file `${java.home}/lib/swing.properties` for similar properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
menu.setBorderPainted(true);
UIManager.put("PopupMenu.border",BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
```